# Dependency injection, ERROR [app-router] Error

Tags: dependency-injection, aurelia

I am having issues with using dependency injection, I have many players which can be accessed via

```
      { route: 'player/:id',  moduleId: 'player', name:'player' }
```

And inside my game class I can successfully create the player objects and list them in my game.html like this, and link them to the correct route.

```
  <ul>
    <li repeat.for="player of players">
      <span>
          ${player.name}
      </span>
      <button click.trigger="removePlayer(player)">Remove</button>
      <a route-href="route: player; params.bind: {id:player.id}">
        player link
      </a>
    </li>
  </ul>
```

But when I try to use DI on my player class where I inject a game object like below it wont work.

```
import {inject} from 'aurelia-framework';
//import {Draw} from './draw';
import {Game} from './game';

let id = 0;

function getId(){
  return ++id;
}

@inject(Game)
export class Player {
  constructor(name, game) {
    this.name = name;
    this.game = game;
    //this.drawing = new Draw(this);
    this.score = 0;
    this.id = getId();
  }

  activate(params, routeConfig) {
    console.log("test");
    console.log(params);
  }

  created() {
    console.log("created player");
  }
}
```

I get the following error when I go to localhost:9000/#/player/1:

```
ERROR [app-router] Error: Error invoking Player. Check the inner error for details.
------------------------------------------------
Inner Error:
Message: key/value cannot be null or undefined. Are you trying to inject/register something that doesn't exist with DI?
Inner Error Stack:
```

I am new to aurelia, and not sure what is wrong here?

Comment: In your constructor, the first parameter is name. if you inspect that, I think you will see that it is getting the game class object. Take out the name parameter and the problem should go away.

Comment: I removed it, and still the same issue. I create the player object like this now inside my game class which has a players array, "this.players.push(new Player(this));" so this inside the parenthesis should tell the player to set the correct game object right?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand. If you are providing the player object with a game object, then you shouldn't be injecting it. Dependency Injection is used when you want the container to handle the management(creation, destruction) of these types of dependencies. If you are explicitly providing them, then you don't need to use the DI container.

Comment: Yes I think you are correct, I will have to reconsider my implementation. thx

Comment: The issue here, I'm fairly sure, is that you've got your constructor expecting 2 properties, but you're only injecting one.

Comment: You have a circular reference, you're importing Game in the player file and you're also importing Player in the Game file